# setting row names on rdist.earth data frame

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and I am trying to set the row names of a data frame I created using `rdist.earth`

The data frame is called `distance` and I want row names correlated to site codes that I have from my fieldwork, with the site codes formatted in a .csv file. The site codes have been called `site_trap`

```
site_trap <- read.csv("site_trap.csv", header=T)
```

I have used the command

```
rownames(distance) <- site_trap 

Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
   invalid 'row.names' length
```

but continue to get this error. Can anyone give me any advice?

Comment: Try `site_trap <- read.csv("site_trap.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE); rownames(distance) <- unlist(site_trap)`

Comment: Hi Richard, I got this error following that advice                                                        > site_trap<-read.csv("site_trap.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> rownames(distance) <- unlist(site_trap)
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘ANC01’, ‘ARC01’, ‘ARC02’, ‘ARC03’, ‘ARC04’, ‘ARC05’, ‘ARC06’, ‘BAC01’, ‘BAC02’,  [... truncated]

Comment: Okay, try `rownames(distance) <- make.unique(unlist(site_trap))`. You can't have duplicates in the data frame row names, this will make them all unique

Comment: Thanks so much Richard! That got it done

Comment: No problem.  I posted the answer below, you can click the gray check-mark to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

First, read the data with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` because we need them as characters.  Then use `make.unique()` to make the row names unique, since data frames do not allow duplicate row names.

```
site_trap <- read.csv("site_trap.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rownames(distance) <- make.unique(unlist(site_trap))
```

Side note:  `header = TRUE` is the default in `read.csv()` so that argument is not necessary.

Not sure if you only have one row in the file or not, but this one-liner might also work.

```
rownames(distance) <- make.unique(scan("site_trap.csv", what = "", sep = ","))
```